# select Query Returns Row Number (Dynamic Number as 1,2,3,4..Sequence) as per Row count

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have table named "Invoice".

```
 ID         InvoiceNo         invoiceDate       main_key    
 1          100078            10.10.2018        1    
 2          400058            10.10.2018        1    
 3          78778             10.10.2018        1    
 4          78778             10.10.2018        2    
 5          78778             10.10.2018        1
```

I need to display data row number in `combobox` using `vb.net`, that is, to display only invoice serial number and to add `id` as valuemember to the combobox.

I tried this

```
SELECT (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM Invoice
        WHERE A.ID >= ID
        ) AS ColumnId
    ,ID AS ColumnCode
FROM Invoice AS A
WHERE A.main_key = 1
```

In this table main_key is key to main_table that has buyer and seller data.

While using `where` condition this query returns wrong sequence of row number.

Please help me guys...Thanks in advance ..!

Comment: What purpose does this calculated value serve in combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want sequential number within each main_key group, consider:

```
SELECT (
        SELECT count(*)
        FROM Invoice
        WHERE A.ID >= ID AND A.main_key=main_key
        ) AS ColumnId
    ,ID AS ColumnCode
FROM Invoice AS A
WHERE A.main_key = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you So Much June7 . Its Working Fine